# Error in Invalid ID 0x00000000 in basic application

Tags: android, android-studio

I have very basic activity application created with Android Studio wizard. But why I'm getting error `E  Invalid ID 0x00000000.` logcat? Application runs in Android 11 API 30 emulator.

Log:

```
2024-03-05 18:05:59.402 13511-13511 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.tst.test_service                 D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-03-05 18:05:59.477 13511-13527 System                  com.tst.test_service                 W  A resource failed to call close. 
2024-03-05 18:05:59.485 13511-13537 libEGL                  com.tst.test_service                 D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2024-03-05 18:05:59.488 13511-13537 libEGL                  com.tst.test_service                 D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2024-03-05 18:05:59.491 13511-13537 libEGL                  com.tst.test_service                 D  loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2024-03-05 18:05:59.593 13511-13511 AppCompatDelegate       com.tst.test_service                 D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
2024-03-05 18:05:59.678 13511-13511 st.test_servic          com.tst.test_service                 E  Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2024-03-05 18:05:59.748 13511-13511 st.test_servic          com.tst.test_service                 W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-03-05 18:05:59.748 13511-13511 st.test_servic          com.tst.test_service                 W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2024-03-05 18:05:59.954 13511-13511 Choreographer           com.tst.test_service                 I  Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-03-05 18:06:00.014 13511-13535 HostConnection          com.tst.test_service                 D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeb1e0760, tid 13535
2024-03-05 18:06:00.018 13511-13535 HostConnection          com.tst.test_service                 D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2024-03-05 18:06:00.019 13511-13535 OpenGLRenderer          com.tst.test_service                 W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2024-03-05 18:06:00.031 13511-13535 EGL_emulation           com.tst.test_service                 D  eglCreateContext: 0xeb1e12c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2024-03-05 18:06:00.088 13511-13535 EGL_emulation           com.tst.test_service                 D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xeb1e12c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xbc976ab0) (first time)
2024-03-05 18:06:00.104 13511-13535 Gralloc4                com.tst.test_service                 I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2024-03-05 18:06:00.105 13511-13535 HostConnection          com.tst.test_service                 D  createUnique: call
2024-03-05 18:06:00.105 13511-13535 HostConnection          com.tst.test_service                 D  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xeb1e2670, tid 13535
2024-03-05 18:06:00.106 13511-13535 goldfish-address-space  com.tst.test_service                 D  allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
2024-03-05 18:06:00.107 13511-13535 goldfish-address-space  com.tst.test_service                 D  allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
2024-03-05 18:06:00.110 13511-13535 HostConnection          com.tst.test_service                 D  HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
2024-03-05 18:06:00.148 13511-13535 OpenGLRenderer          com.tst.test_service                 I  Davey! duration=707ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=3550308496207, Vsync=3550825162853, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=3550839799700, AnimationStart=3550839851400, PerformTraversalsStart=3550840685700, DrawStart=3550998421400, SyncQueued=3551001820600, SyncStart=3551019359600, IssueDrawCommandsStart=3551019448800, SwapBuffers=3551032163600, FrameCompleted=3551033766800, DequeueBufferDuration=285500, QueueBufferDuration=455600, GpuCompleted=72904454231491230, 
2024-03-05 18:06:05.262 13511-13540 ProfileInstaller        com.tst.test_service                 D  Installing profile for com.tst.test_service
```

Application:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```